# How to read data from multiple kafka topics and compare the data objects

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I want to read data from two topics(one for existing application topic, second for same application with performance optimztn) 
and measure whether data coming is same after performance optimization.

My Kafka Topics consist of data in the form of

```
case class Json(id: String, event: String,ingestion_ts: Long, data: Map[String, String])
```

The processing work is taking place in Spark Streaming.
 1. Is it good idea to create two stream jobs and compare the data using join

```
val windowedStream1 = stream1.window(Seconds(30))
    val windowedStream2 = stream2.window(Minutes(1))
    val joinedStream = windowedStream1.join(windowedStream2)
```

2. Or create single stream and read data from both topics and compare
3. For comparison do we need to use any window function, bcz after optimization kafka topics recieving data 
   in more frequently than earlier application. 
   Or is there any other mechanism to compare two objects?

   Flow diagram.

   1. Application  ==> Kafka Topic (t1)
      2.Optimized Application ==> Kafka Topic(t2)

Intended flow diagram 
    3. kafka Topic(t1, t2)  => Spark Streaming (Data Comparision) => HDFS

I have followed option 2 here and code is as below.

```
message1.foreachRDD(rdd => {
        var af = new HashSet[JsonOnj]
        var af2 = new HashSet[JsonOnj]
        val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
        rdd.foreachPartition(iter => {
          val offsets = offsetRanges(TaskContext.getPartitionId())
          if (offsets.topic.equalsIgnoreCase("myTopic2")) {
            iter.foreach(x => {
              af += jsonParser(x._2)
            })
          } else {
            iter.foreach(x => {
              af2 += jsonParser(x._2)
            })
          }
        })
        if (af.size == af2.size)
          log.info(s":: :: :: $af.isEmpty :::: $af2.isEmpty :: " + af.sameElements(af2))
        else
          log.info(s"########:: :: :: count does not match" + af.size + "  " + af2.size)
      } 
    })
```

In above code under foreachPartition I can able to add Json parsed object into HashSet. 
Though in foreachPartition I have been adding parsed object to mutable set(one each for two kafka topics) and outside foreachPartition sets are empty.

I am not able to understand how code works inside foreachRDD?
Any code changes do I need to make. Please suggest